# Counting matching character values

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS and I have a basic question about counting the number of matching values in a column.
For example, if I have a variable called hair_color, and the different values are "brown", "black", "blonde", and "red" - I want to be able to produce a table that shows my database has 45 people with brown hair, 43 with black hair, 23 with blonde, etc.
I've written:

```
proc freq data=fake_dataset;
tables hair_color; 
where hair_color="brown" "black" "blonde" "red";
run;
```

This code only runs if I have one value in the 'where' statement, for example, only "brown". How can I create a table of counts for all four hair colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Proc FREQ` will create a bin for each distinct value of `hair_color`.  If you have more than the four colors you listed but want only counts of those four, you will want to use the `IN` operator in the `where` clause

```
proc freq data=fake_dataset;
  tables hair_color; 
  where hair_color in ("brown", "black", "blonde", "red");
run;
```

The commas separating the values list in the `IN` clause are optional.